# "No Animation Data In Buffer To Paste" Error

Tags: animation, error

Ive been animating a run cycle and I need to copy and mirror the same poses.
[image: on frame 10 i copied that frame and on frame 14 i hit shift+ ctrl+v to paste the copied frame and it gave me this error]

On frame 10 I copied that frame and on frame 14 I hit <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> to paste the copied frame and it gave me this error: `no animation data in buffer to paste`

Ive looked for a setting that could be enabled and could not find one that looked like it did anything with it
I'm using 2.90.1

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out I had to have my mouse over the view screen.
I had my mouse over the dope sheet